# wkhtmltopdf - Creating PDF when browser page width is greater than 2000px

Tags: php, css, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf PHP library to create pdf and it is creating PDF fine.

But when the browser page width is greater than 4000px then I am not able to convert all page to PDF.

The code I am using is

```
exec("C:\Progra~1\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf -O landscape --dpi 3000 MY_URL mypdf.pdf 2>> err3.txt 1>> out3.txt");
```

Any solution?

Thanks